# Spring Boot business metrics. Micrometer & Prometheus or InfluxDB

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, influxdb, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

We need in our system to calculate and visualize a couple of business metrics like:

- total number of transactions processed over last configured time interval
- average processing time over last configured time interval
- max processing time over last configured time interval
- min processing time over last configured time interval

I have to expose these metrics somehow from SpringBoot application.

I checked whether it is possible to calculate this type of metrics at the application level (Spring boot) using the Micrometer library built into the Spring Boot Actuator. Unfortunately, I don't see that it allows using Meters to calculate the average value or the minimum value of particular method execution (with configured time interval)

The use of Prometheus also doesn't seem to be the best idea because it works on the pull-based principle. It seems to me that this may render the results inaccurate and delayed because of scraping intervals.

My last idea is to write each transaction processing time to InfluxDB or a similar DB and then, using queries get the results I need (business metrics). However, I am worried about the efficiency of this solution as it introduces additional time to each business transaction

What do you think about it? Am I right about the limitations of the Micrometer? Does the idea from influxDB sound reasonable? Maybe another way to approach this problem?

Comment: If these metrics are intended to help monitor the system, and understand its health, then Micrometer + Prometheus is a good fit. However, if the goal is to not miss a single transaction because this tracking is intended for long term reporting, then Micrometer is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Which stack/tool do you think will fit better to this kind of measurments (detailed business metrics, kpi)? Pushed-based time-series db like Influx?

Comment: What is the goal? To gauge aggregate performance or to run the business?

Comment: Yeah, the first one - gauge aggregate performance